# En qué carpeta dentro de Roaming reside una aplicación de Visual Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Si en modo Debug ejecuto

```
Dim appDataPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
MsgBox(appDataPath)
```

Obtengo una salida del tipo

C:\Users\MiUsuario\AppData\Roaming

pero dentro de Roaming hay varias carpetas y no encuentro ninguna con un nombre que corresponda con mi aplicación o que pueda ubicarla por fecha y hora de creación

Dónde reside realmente mi aplicación dentro de Roaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Windows 7+ Las aplicaciones por defecto se crean en

`C:\Users\<NombreUsuario>\Documents\Visual Studio 20XX\Projects`
Allí se guardan los proyectos que creas *(Si no has cambiado la ruta de donde haces los nuevos proyectos)*.

La ruta que utilizas en el código, pertenece a la carpeta *especial* `%appdata%` *(Roaming)*.

Para saber donde se encuentra tu ejecutable actual, puedes utilizar:

```
Dim Path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
MsgBox(Path)
```

En los **remarks** de la referencia, dice claramente:

> El valor por defecto de esta propiedad es el directorio donde se encuentra el ejecutable del proceso actual, ejemplo:
>
> Si tu ejecutable se encuentra en el directorio `C:\MiAplicacion\App.exe`, el código anterior va a imprimir en el `MessageBox`:
>
> `C:\MiAplicacion`

#### EDIT:

Hay otra forma que hace uso de la variable `Environment.CurrentDirectory` y es la de `IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, el principio es el mismo, esta función solo devuelve el valor de la propiedad de `Enviroment`.

Referencia (ingles):

- `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
- `IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Saludos.

Comment: Correcto, muchas gracias @NaCI

En mi caso si genero el instalador con ClickOnce y luego ejecuto el programa ya instalado la ruta me da algo como

C:\Users\MiUsuario\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\KNOQOGWL.EEC\KXXZMW8E.CZ8\indp..tion_025ef450a4430b8b_0001.0000_46a8bd13d0aef768

Una ruta bien amena y fácil de recordar :)

Pero lo peor es que también genera en el mismo nivel, en ...\KNOQOGWL.EEC\KXXZMW8E.CZ8\ varias carpetas más con los componentes que usa el programa, por ejemplo itextsharp.... manifest... sys.sqlite...

Comment: Supongo que es lo normal por un tema de seguridad y que Windows se encargar de gestionar esas carpetas automáticamente al momento de desinstalar el programa.

Comment: Es parte de la instalación por ClickOnce, posiciona la instalación en uno que otro directorio por cuestiones de seguridad.

Comment: @NaCI comprendido, muchas gracias